# Suddenly all my scripts fail to resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am making a AngularJS app for a school project. I am using AngularJS, Material, Bower, Bootstrap and Yeoman. Everything was working fine but know my scripts fail to resolve, i resolved a few doing it manually but now i see all the scripts are failing to resolve, making me think there is another issue.

[image: Code]

[image: Webstorm note]

Anyone know what i did :O?

Comment: Can you give us the file structure, seems like he doesn"t find your files

Comment: Did you try running the command `bower install` to make sure all your project dependencies are installed?

Comment: is bower_components directory is on your index.html dir ? if not; you have to edit src to access to the correct bower_components location

Comment: What do you mean by "I resolved a few doing it manually" ?

Comment: Folder structure: http://imgur.com/a/QRUHl
Bower install did not work.

Comment: I manually changed the script path so that the script is found. I just think it's weird that all of the sudden all my scripts are not resolved therefore not wanting to change everything manually.

Comment: @Alexi Coard added

Comment: What is the error you got in your bower install ?

Comment: It gives nothing back when in run bower install. @Alexi Coard

Comment: Anyone know this?